# Dot in haskell, tricky example

Tags: haskell

I know that "haskells dot" question was answered couple times before on stackoverflow but I came across a example that shows me I still don't fully get it. Let's say I have functions

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f x = x
g x = \y -> y
```

Now, as far as I know dot works like function composition -> `f (g x) = (f . g) x`
. So

`(f . g) 4 5`

shuld returns 5. Because `g` takes two arguments and returns second one, and f is simply identity. However it doesn't, Im getting `Couldn't match type` error. I have a feeling that haskell parses this expresion to something like `((f . g) 4) 5`. But I need deeper explanation

Comment: It does return 5. Maybe you typed in something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, we have:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

Hence, in particular

```
(f . g) 4 = f (g 4)               (*)
```

from which we have

```
(f . g) 4 5
=   -- application associates to the left
((f . g) 4) 5
=   -- equation (*) above
(f (g 4)) 5 =
=   -- application associates to the left
f (g 4) 5
```

We can now see that the last argument `5` is being left as the second argument of `f`, and *not* passed to `g`.

It is useful to remember that Haskell functions are curried: technically, there's no such a thing as a function which takes two arguments. A function having type `a -> b -> c` is actually a unary function returning a unary function, even if we like to think of that as a binary function.

The composition operator works on unary functions as well: `f . g` composes the unary functions `f` and `g`. If `f` is "binary", it is treated as a unary function returning a function. This makes it take an additional argument, as shown above. If `g` is "binary", its returned function is passed to `f`.

So, using the above definitions:

```
f x = x
g x = \y -> y
```

we get:

```
(f . g) 4 5
= -- done above
f (g 4) 5
= -- associativity
(f (g 4)) 5
= -- definition of f
(g 4) 5
= -- definition of g
(\y -> y) 5
= -- beta reduction
5
```

Comment: I forgot to mention type of f in my question. It was Integer -> Integer. This is why I was getting error

Answer (score 0):

```
main = print $(f . g) 4 5

f x = x
g x = \y -> y
```

Compiles nicely and when run prints 5. I'm using GHC 8.0.1.
Maybe you'd rather provide a complete minimal etc. example?